# onClick will not work at the same time as onChange

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onchange

I've been trying for hours to figure out how I can target an iframe with onchange and then when I click on the button it will pop up a new window or tab.

```
function changeLocation(locationUrl)
{
 document.getElementById('iframetest').src=locationUrl
}
function subm()
{
var form = document.jump;
var value = document.jump.TSdropdown.options[document.jump.TSdropdown.selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
    form.target = 'value';
    form.submit();
}
}

<form name="jump" method="post" action="" target="">
    <select name="TSdropdown" onchange="changeLocation(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option selected = "selected">Choose a Model Run</option>
    //option values
    <input class="button" type="button" id="btn" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="subm();">
    </select>
</form>
</td>

</tr>


<tr>
<td class="centered">
<div id="outerdiv">
<iframe height="400" width="940" name="iframetest" id="iframetest" src=""></iframe>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The button click does not go to a new window and I cannot figure out how to do it

Comment: Are you trying to open a new window on click of submit button?, your question is not clear.

Comment: Yes I would like to have the link previewed with an iframe which is traggered by onchange and then when I click, the selection would pop up in a new window or tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no element by id 'jump', use `document.jump` instead of `document.getElementById('jump');`

to get the value of selected dropdown, use:

```
var value = document.jump.TSdropdown.options[document.jump.TSdropdown.selectedIndex].value
```

now use this `value` variable.

Comment: Thanks, now the submit button actually creates a new page. How would I go about having it go to the url selected by the drop down menu?

Comment: Like so?function subm()
{
var form = document.jump;
var value = document.jump.TSdropdown.options[document.jump.TSdropdown.selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
    form.target = 'value';
    form.submit();
}
}

Comment: What is the issue, try to alert the values in the javascript and check whether you are getting correct values or not. Also, How are you creating a new page and what do you mean by creating a new page? can you tell what exactly are you trying to do??

Comment: Well I am trying to create javascript in which when a user selects an item from the drop down menu, a website in an iframe appears. I have gotten this to work, but additionally, I want to have it so when you press the submit button, a new window will come up and start a download (it would be a different url than the one that comes up on the iframe). The iframe is sort of like a preview before you have to download a very large file.

Comment: ok, so how have you created the new window, which you are saying is working?

Comment: yes, a new window pops up, but it is the same url that the javascript is running on. none of the url values on the drop down are being used. The url values are working for the iframe.

Comment: I made a shortened version of my code that will compile if you run it.

Comment: Use : var value = document.jump.TSdropdown.options[document.jump.TSdropdown.selectedIndex].value;
window.open(value, '_blank');

Comment: That worked for the Test 1 option but not for any of the other values for some reason

Comment: Actually, it only is working the first time you submit the form. After that it just opens the page you are already on.

Comment: Remove the form submit code as it is not needed, i.e remove : document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
    form.target = 'value';
    form.submit();
}

Comment: No problem, but from next time, try to phrase your question in a way which is easier for others to understand, the help will come quickly that way.